# How do you set SOAPUI JDBC Request step's Connection String from a groovy script?

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I would post this on soapui forums but they won't let me register & don't display any errored field colorings =-=

without finding it in the documentation, i'm walking blind

I've tried this so far, no dice:

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
def db = project.getPropertyValue("dbConnectionString")
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["JDBC Request"].setPropertyValue("Connection String", db)
log.info "db connection string set to "+ db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much confusion & jumping through objects because the JdbcTestRequest wasn't visible in the soapui documentation overview.... found the object in question: https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/JdbcRequestTestStep.html

answer to this is

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["getOfferNames"].setConnectionString(db)
```